# How do I find a certain place name from a list of address and need to return the place name in to next column in excel

Tags: excel

i have a list of address column[as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEWY.jpg) and i have a some list of district Names, can some one can help out if address column containing district name then need to show in the "B" Column as shown in the picture

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Cell B2` enter

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,A2),$D$2:$D$6),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change ranges in formula as per your data.

[image]

***Note :*** This formula will do case sensitive match.

Comment: Hi, can you suggest what changes i need to do, if in address column district name is not in same spelling (if almost if 90% is matching)

Comment: @musthafamuhammed - For partial match there should be a particular pattern for all strings or else its not possible using formula. Best solution will be to add incorrect spelling also in keywords list.